# flush data not working on live ipage server

Tags: javascript, php, progress, flush

long-time lurker, first-time user
looking for help with progress bar during long [php code](http://w3shaman.com/article/php-progress-bar-script)

It works well on xampp, but caches all output and only outputs when finished php code
again, this only happens on live server on xampp, works fine

tried various remedies:

- flush and ob_flush
- php.ini configs
- etc.

to no avail! help!

Comment: If you're a long time lurker, you should really know [ask].

Comment: seems this question doesn't even belong on SO, since it is not about writing the code, but configuring the server... try *Server Fault* - but not before including some more information, for example. **what** is your live server?